Remove dark ring marks on redwood deck

I hired a painter to wash, sand and stain my redwood deck. He finished applying stain yesterday, using a blend of Twp1500 and a little twp200. Today I see ring marks that came from a planter that were not removed prior to staining. The painter said they were ingrained too deep. What should he have done and what can be done now? I appreciate your help and expertise.

only sanding can fix that

Why were the planters not removed prior to staining? Is this one planter or multiple planters?   Perhaps build a new planter to cover the ugly rings.

As mentioned, only sanding can remove the marks. However, they may well be deeply entrenched. Put the same planters back on, but use a tray underneath.
